# Link preview of facebook not working properly

Tags: wordpress, facebook, hyperlink, sharing

I am facing an issue with facebook open graphs. This is the link of the website:

http://pandolin.com/

The problem is that when I share content from my website (for eg: this page http://pandolin.com/crafting-realism-on-celluloid-production-designers-subrata-and-amit/), the image and description of the post are not present in the link preview. I've attached the required screenshots.

The sharing debugger is giving the website

- Response code 0
- Server Id is empty
- og:description is empty
- og:image is empty
- the scraper views an empty page instead of the page source

I've tried all the solutions available online. Please help find the bug and guide me by providing a step by step solution of the problem.

Comment: You can preview and debug your Facebook sharing informations following [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)

Comment: I have already tried, can't resolve the issue https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fpandolin.com%2Fdrug-issue-censor-board-intense-characters-shahid-alia-open-udta-punjab%2F   this is the link

Answer (score 1):

I saw that you're using Yoast plugin for your WordPress site. Maybe you can try the following:

- Log-in into your WordPress CMS dashboard
- Go to "Posts" and navigate  to the desired post, as you would like to edit it
- Scroll down to the bottom of your post, where you will see Yoast
  settings
- Click on the share icon in the Yoast settings, as shown in the image
  below:
  [image]
- Upload your desired image to be shown in the FB share by default

That's it.